# Python Webscraping: How do i loop many url requests?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
LURL="https://www.erkunde-die-welt.de/laender-hauptstaedte-welt/"
Lpage = requests.get(LURL)
Lsoup = BeautifulSoup(Lpage.content, 'html.parser')
Lx = Lsoup.find_all(class_="column-2")
a=[]
for Lx in Lx:
  a.append(Lx.text)
a.remove("Land")
j=0
for i in range(len(a)):
  b = a[j]
  URL = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+b
  page = requests.get(URL)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  l = soup.find(class_="firstHeading")
  zr = soup.find(class_="wikitable infobox infoboxstaat float-right")
  z = zr.findAll("tr")
  a=""
  for z in z:
    a=a+z.text
  h=a.find("Hauptstadt")
  lol=a[h:-1]
  lol=lol.replace("Hauptstadt", "")
  lol=lol.strip()
  fg=lol.find("\n")
  lol=lol[0:fg]
  lol=lol.strip()
  j=j+1
  print(lol)
  print(l.text)
```

This is the code. It gets the name of every country and packs it into a list. After that the program loops through the wikipedia pages of the countrys and gets the capital of the country and prints it. It works fine for every country. But after one country is finished and code starts again it stops do work with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    z = zr.findAll("tr") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

Comment: Alright, what exactly is the issue? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stored the list of countries in a variable called `a`, which you then overwrote later in the script with some other value.  That messes up your iteration.  Two good ways to prevent problems like this:

1. Use more meaningful variable names.
2. Use `mypy` on your Python code.

I spent a little time trying to do some basic cleanup on your code to at least get you past that first bug; the list of countries is now called `countries` instead of `a`, which prevents you from overwriting it, and I replaced the extremely confusing `i/j/a/b` iteration with a very simple `for country in countries` loop.  I also got rid of all the variables that were only used once so I wouldn't have to try to come up with better names for them.  I think there's more work to be done, but I don't have enough of an idea what that inner loop is doing to want to even try to fix it.  Good luck!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

countries = [x.text for x in BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(
        "https://www.erkunde-die-welt.de/laender-hauptstaedte-welt/"
    ).content,
    'html.parser'
).find_all(class_="column-2")]
countries.remove("Land")

for country in countries:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(
            "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + country
        ).content,
        'html.parser'
    )
    heading = soup.find(class_="firstHeading")
    rows = soup.find(
        class_="wikitable infobox infoboxstaat float-right"
    ).findAll("tr")
    a = ""
    for row in rows:
        a += row.text
        h = a.find("Hauptstadt")
        lol = a[h:-1]
        lol = lol.replace("Hauptstadt", "")
        lol = lol.strip()
        fg = lol.find("\n")
        lol = lol[0:fg]
        lol = lol.strip()
        print(lol)
        print(heading.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right this code was really messed up. And it is kind of embarassing that i didnt notice that i accidantaly did overwrite the variable a. Anyways thank you very much that you take some time to look over this messy code and notice the failure. Now its work.

Comment: PS. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

The error message is actually telling you what's happening. The line of code

```
z = zr.findAll("tr")
```

is throwing an attribute error because the NoneType object does not have a `findAll` attribute. You are trying to call `findAll` on zr, assuming that variable will always be a BeautifulSoup object, but it won't. If this line:

```
zr = soup.find(class_="wikitable infobox infoboxstaat float-right")
```

finds no objects in the html matching those classes, zr will be set to `None`. So, on one of the pages you are trying to scrape, that's what happening. You can code around it with a try/except statement, like this:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    b = a[j]
    URL = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+b
    page = requests.get(URL)
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        l = soup.find(class_="firstHeading")
        zr = soup.find(class_="wikitable infobox infoboxstaat float-right")
        z = zr.findAll("tr")
        a=""
        #don't do this! should be 'for i in z' or something other variable name
        for z in z:
            a=a+z.text
            h=a.find("Hauptstadt")
            lol=a[h:-1]
            lol=lol.replace("Hauptstadt", "")
            lol=lol.strip()
            fg=lol.find("\n")
            lol=lol[0:fg]
            lol=lol.strip()
            j=j+1
            print(lol)
            print(l.text)
    except:
        pass
```

In this example, any page that doesn't have the right html tags will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The 'NoneType' means your line `zr = soup.find(class_="wikitable infobox infoboxstaat float-right")` has returned nothing.

The error is in this loop :

```
  for Lx in Lx:
      a.append(Lx.text)
```

You can't use the same name there. Please try to use this loop instead and let me know how it goes:

```
  for L in Lx:
         a.append(Lx.text)
```